# I have an interesting questions in python i cant understand it is about return value and fruitful function i guess

Tags: python

2.3.1. Area of rectangle
The parameters length and width represent the lengths of the sides of a rectangle. Calculate the area of the rectangle with the given values, and return the result.

Examples:

```
rectangle_area(5, 10) → 50

rectangle_area(1, 10) → 10

rectangle_area(2, 6) → 12
```

My code is :

```
def rectangle_area(length, width):
    return 0


Result  Actual Value    Expected Value  Notes
Fail    0               50              rectangle_area(5, 10)
Fail    0               10              rectangle_area(1, 10)
Fail    0               12              rectangle_area(2, 6)
Fail    0               1               rectangle_area(1, 1)
Fail    0               15              rectangle_area(3, 5)
Fail    0               60              rectangle_area(15, 4)
You passed: 0.0% of the tests
```

it showed me this so how can I solve this... is there any way to pass this.

Comment: def rectangle_area(length, width):
    return (length * width)
so this is the solution

Comment: def rectangle_area(length, width):
    return (length * width)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
def rectagle_area(length, width) :
    return (length * width)
```

Comment: 2.3.6. Using Your Is Even Function
Write a program that continues to take in a number from the user until the number given is NOT even. For example, the user might enter 4, 10, 42, 5. The program would only stop when the non-even number 5 is entered. You need to use the is_even function.